# Specific locations and menu items for each bundled card

Tags: java, google-mirror-api, google-glass

Is it possible to define a specific location and menu item options for each bundled card?
I am currently developing in Java, and not sure if I can include such parameters in TimelineItem.setHtmlPages(List) method.
I'd like some of the bundled cards to have a menu item to allow navigation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with a "HTML Bundle".

You would have to create several timeline items with a common `bundleId`.

Then you have full control over the contents and options of each separate card.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [threading](https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline#bundling_cards), which is used to bundle together related items.

Threading allows you to define different menu items for each item in a bundle. To thread together a series of timeline items, specify the same `bundleId` for each  `timelineItem.bundleId`.

Currently, there is no method to easily assign a specific order for each item in a bundle, but this is a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=56). You can choose one timeline item to be the cover of the bundle by setting `timelineItem.isBundleCover` of that item to `true`. Beyond this, timeline items are automatically sorted in the order of when they were last updated. One hack to try to order item right now is to just update all the items in the bundle in the order that you want them to appear.

Bundling can easily be used incorrectly, so be sure to also check out the [design guidelines](https://developers.google.com/glass/ui-guidelines#bundling_timeline_cards).